EventID 51: "An error was detected on device during a paging operation", but disks are fine
We are an MSP and receive this warning on several servers. But we are pretty sure all is fine.

An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk2\DR3 during a paging operation


https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/event-id-51-information states:

The computer may log this event message when it loads images from a storage device, reads, and writes to locally mapped files or to any file (as long as it's buffered I/O). The computer doesn't log this event message when it performs nonbuffered I/O.

We have Hyper-V hosts, often with one Windows Server VM.

In the Windows Server VM we use Windows Server Backup.
It creates backups to  drive E:
Drive E: in the VM is a .vhdx file on the Hyper-V host, on a separate large SATA disk. It is separate from the RAID volume that holds the VM, and not on USB.

We do this as an extra backup, we also create offsite backups of the whole VM.
I don't think it's an actual disk problem.
We notice these errors often, on new and older disks. It looks we can safely ignore them.
We also want to keep alerts from our server monitoring tools when warnings of source Disk appear in Eventlog.
Could this be caused by heavy load on the (virtual) disk?
Could this be caused by an conflict in disk access? For example, VSS accessing the disk when Windows Server Backup is running?
What could cause these errors?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/event-id-51-information seems that you did no or not well enough research imho

@djdomi, I did. I checked all bytes and it leads to the same error message as in the text of the error. The documentation doesn't provide solutions, only error messages. And the errors are very complex. such as IO_WARNING_PAGING_FAILURE, SRB_STATUS_QUEUE_FROZEN. SCSI_SENSE_NO_SENSE. For sure it's not a bad block on the disk, and I'm not missing driver updates. All looks fine. How to fix this then? It's not very helpful of Microsoft.

Microsoft is legendary for poor or misleading error messages. Nothing here will change that. However, the question is missing most information and symptom elaboration that would be relevant and meaningful. Most people would add a filter and move on.
